# Wordpress on nginx non-ASCII characters in URL with 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, url, nginx, character-encoding

I have a wordpress site and when I use Arabic characters for the url address of my page I get a 404 Error but when I rename the link name for my page with english characters it works!

I found this question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277401/arabic-characters-in-url-returns-404-error) but the solution there did not work for me! It makes sense that this is related somehow to .htaccess file, but I already have other wordpress sites which are working with arabic urls and have the same .htaccess content!

Comment: For peoples who know Persian [this link](http://forum.wp-parsi.com/topic/23607-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%AF%D9%86-%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D8%A7-url-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C/) may be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-and-nginx-404-errors-all-but-home-page) helped me solve my problem. Specifically adding

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }
```

to the corresponding configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` worked for me!